# Pulling Weather API Data and tweeting it

Tags: javascript, node.js

Apixu recently updated their endpoints(now weatherstack) and I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix my twitter weather bot. I am stuck right now with the following code

*now fixed*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're giving us a snippet or the full file, but you're not invoking your setup function.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it turns out I forgot to install the axios package, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed certain things here (If you have sent the whole file content):

1) Import the Twit instance from package of twitter to send the post request.
2) Calling the setup() function from somewhere in the file.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it turns out I forgot to install the package, it's working now.

Answer (score -1):

Ok it turns out I forgot to install the axios package, it's working now.